# What are the "25 bespoke tools (that) had to be developed" to install a new coolant system for the Alpha Magnetic Spectrometer (AMS)?

Tags: iss, nasa, eva, alpha-magnetic-spectrometer

The [2020 Jan/Feb issue of the CERN Courier](https://cerncourier.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/CERNCourier2020JanFeb-digitaledition.pdf) has an astronaut on its front cover and on the next page *From the Editor* begins:

> It’s not often that CERN Courier has the opportunity to feature an astronaut on its cover, but events unfolding 400 km above Earth’s surface in recent weeks more than merit such a decision. Photographed on 2 December, **NASA astronaut Drew Morgan is seen installing a new coolant system for the Alpha Magnetic Spectrometer (AMS)** – the unique cosmic-ray detector masterminded by charm–quark co-discoverer Sam Ting of MIT and assembled by an international team at CERN. AMS has been attached to the International Space Station (ISS) since 2011 and initially was intended to operate for three years. **Never designed to be serviceable, some 25 bespoke tools had to be developed for the procedure**, which involved four high profile extravehicular activities (EVAs) and years of preparation involving hundreds of astronauts, engineers and scientists on the ground. It is deemed one of the most complex interventions in space since repairs to the Hubble Space Telescope and will keep AMS operating until the end of the decade.

**Question:** What are at least some of these "25 bespoke tools"? What are they for, who developed them and when did they start?

"bonus points" for a snapshot of an astronaut using one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Tumblr](https://nasa.tumblr.com/post/189210016829/from-discovering-the-secrets-of-the-universe-to)

#### Goddard:

1. Debris Shield Capture Cage
2. Debris Shield Handling Aid
3. #10 Allen Bit
4. Top Spacer tool
5. Fastener Capture Block
6. Nadir Tube Cutting Guide tool
7. Zenith Tube Cutting Guide tool
8. VSB Cover Handling Aid
9. Hex Head Capture tool
10. Socket Head Capture tool

    #### Johnson:
11. Tube cap
12. Vacuum Case Handrail - Nadir
13. Vacuum Case Handrail - Zenith
14. Diagonal Beam Handrail
15. EVA Zip Tie Cutter [(being "used" by an astronaut)](https://roundupreads.jsc.nasa.gov/images/imagefull-3840.png)
16. Clean Cutter
17. Tube Straightener
18. Tool Board
19. Tube Puller
20. 7/8" EVA combination wrench
21. Rough cutter

[Spacewalk video](https://youtu.be/evaBhht5uGA?t=8731)

From a [blog](https://www.nasa.gov/johnson/HWHAP/alpha-magnetic-spectrometer-the-tools):

Heather Bergman was the JSC EVA tools Project Manager for the AMS repair tools

This blog also mentions:

22. Tube Labels (like finger traps)

Comment: Lots of info here: https://www.nasa.gov/johnson/HWHAP/alpha-magnetic-spectrometer-the-tools

Comment: Some pix: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37b2Z6J0zKc

Comment: More pix including in-use pix: https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=49551.60

Comment: I quite like [this video](https://youtu.be/37b2Z6J0zKc?t=760)

Comment: Wiki created as a good answer is likely to involve "25" sub-answers, which would be a daunting task for anyone, so hopefully this provides a framework for people with snippets of information to contribute.

Comment: @JCRM this worked out very well, thanks!

Comment: I was hoping for much more detail @uhoh

Comment: @JCRM okay I've un-accepted for now